# "Order by" in a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, union

I am trying to select the student that has most hours of Kindness of each grade (9-12). I wrote this code (in sql server 2012) to get the student with most hours:

```
(select top 1  stu_first, stu_last, sum(KIND_hours) as total from STUDENT inner join KIND
on student.stu_id=KIND.stu_id
where (12-(STU_CLASS_OF-2014))=9
group by stu_first, stu_last
order by total desc)
```

This code works, but when I try to union the code together for just two grades I get this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
My code is here

```
(select top 1  stu_first, stu_last, sum(KIND_hours) as total from STUDENT inner join KIND
on student.stu_id=KIND.stu_id
where (12-(STU_CLASS_OF-2014))=9
group by stu_first, stu_last
order by total desc)
union
(select top 1  stu_first, stu_last, sum(KIND_hours) as total from STUDENT inner join KIND
on student.stu_id=KIND.stu_id
where (12-(STU_CLASS_OF-2014))=10
group by stu_first, stu_last
order by total desc)
```

stu_class_of is the year that the student would graduate

Comment: Order By clause cannot be used in sub query.

Comment: you you can use order by in a sub query for example:      select absence.abs_date, (12 - (stu_class_of - 2014)) as grade,
count( absence.abs_date)as total from student
inner join absence on student.STU_ID=absence.stu_id
where absence.abs_date in
(select top 5 (absence.abs_date) from absence
group by abs_date
order by count(absence.abs_date) desc)
group by abs_date, STU_CLASS_OF
order by abs_date, total

Comment: yes you can order by in sub-query along with TOP clause.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo Of course you can, why not? `ORDER BY` has been commonly used in sub-queries to select the first/last record(s) in databases where things like `TOP`, `FIRST/LAST`, `LIMIT`, etc... are not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Make your 2 queries.."derived" Tables.  Here is a working Northwind example:

```
  Use Northwind
     GO

Select  OrderID , CustomerID , EmployeeID from 
( Select TOP 1 OrderID , CustomerID , EmployeeID from  dbo.Orders where ShipCountry='France' Order by ShippedDate )
as derived1
UNION ALL
Select  OrderID , CustomerID , EmployeeID from 
( Select TOP 1 OrderID , CustomerID , EmployeeID from  dbo.Orders where ShipCountry='Germany' Order by ShippedDate  )
as derived2
```

Here it is with your queries plugged in , but I cannot test them since I don't have your DDL.

```
    Select  * from 
    ( select top 1  stu_first, stu_last, sum(KIND_hours) as total from STUDENT inner join KIND
on student.stu_id=KIND.stu_id
where (12-(STU_CLASS_OF-2014))=9
group by stu_first, stu_last
order by total desc )
    as derived1
    UNION ALL
    Select  * from 
    ( select top 1  stu_first, stu_last, sum(KIND_hours) as total from STUDENT inner join KIND
on student.stu_id=KIND.stu_id
where (12-(STU_CLASS_OF-2014))=10
group by stu_first, stu_last
order by total desc  )
    as derived2
```

OLD ANSWER FOR POSSIBLE WORK AROUND

If you need "Order by" distinction between the two sets of data, you can use this trick:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableTwo') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableTwo
end



CREATE TABLE #TableOne
( 
SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1) , 
NameOfOne varchar(12)
)



CREATE TABLE #TableTwo
( 
SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1) , 
NameOfTwo varchar(12)
)


Insert into #TableOne (NameOfOne)
Select 'C' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'B' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'D' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'Z' as Alpha


Insert into #TableTwo (NameOfTwo)
Select 'T' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'W' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'X' as Alpha UNION ALL Select 'A' as Alpha



select 1 , NameOfOne from #TableOne
UNION
select 2 , NameOfTwo from #TableTwo
Order by 1 , 2 /* These are the "Ordinal Positions of the Column*/




IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableTwo') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableTwo
end
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are suggesting

Comment: If you need the "top 1" item from the first-query...to show up before the "top 1" item for the second query....you can use this trick of putting a "1" (or "2") as the value of the first column.

Comment: I do not understand how your trick works, can you explain it to me?

Comment: Run my query.  And ask yourself "Why does the 'Z' show up on the 4th row, and not the last row" in the result-set.

Comment: I added a new answer to the top of this response.  "derived"

Comment: Your suggestion works, but why was it necessary to treat the query as a table?

Comment: To get around the ORDER BY issue.  You want distinct ORDER-BY's.  But a union will only (allow a) Order-By  (on) the entire result-set.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I want to order a sub-query I tend it to wrap in an outer query like this:

```
select * from 
(select * from xx order by x) x
```

This way yo can embed this query in a UNION or any other situation and it will always work since you apply the sort in the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

Your UNION shouldn't be 2 subselects. You need to remove 1 of the ORDER BYs:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Id INT);
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1), (2), (3);

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (Id INT);
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (7), (9), (-1);


SELECT * FROM @T1
UNION
SELECT * FROM @T2
ORDER BY Id DESC;


/* Output:
9 --From @T2
7 --From @T2
3
2
1
-1 --From @T2
*/
```

Edit: I realize now what it is that you actually want. I should have realized by seeing your TOP 1's combined with a UNION. What you're actually looking for is called a CTE (Common Table Expression). Here's the query you're looking for:

```
/*
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [STUDENT] ON;
INSERT INTO [STUDENT] (stu_id, stu_first, stu_last, STU_CLASS_OF) VALUES
(1,  'Leonard', 'Hofstadter', 1989),
(2, 'Sheldon', 'Cooper', 1989),
(3, 'Howard', 'Wolowitz', 1989),
(4, 'Raj', 'Koothrappali', 1989),
(5, 'Penny', '?', 2001),
(6, 'Bernadette', 'Rostenkowski ', 2001),
(7, 'Amy', 'Fowler', 2001)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [STUDENT] OFF;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [KIND] ON;
INSERT INTO [KIND] (stu_id, [hours]) VALUES
(1,  10),
(2, 13),
(3, 7),
(4, 54),
(5, 78),
(6, 13),
(7, 64)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [KIND] OFF;
*/

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [STU_CLASS_OF] ORDER BY SUM([KIND].[hours]) DESC) AS [RowNumber],
        [stu_first],
        [stu_last],
        SUM([KIND].[hours]) AS [total]
    FROM [STUDENT]
        INNER JOIN [KIND] ON [STUDENT].[stu_id] = [KIND].[stu_id]
    GROUP BY [stu_first], [stu_last], [STU_CLASS_OF]
)
SELECT
    [stu_first],
    [stu_last],
    [total]
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY [STU_CLASS_OF] DESC;
```

Here's a short explination of what's actually going on behind the scenes:
A CTE is like a subselect, but it has a lot of awesome features. One of them is `ROW_NUMBER()` which gives an ID each time it sees whatever you write in the `PARTION BY {something}`.

But if it did that randomly, you'd get different results each time. So you also add an `ORDER BY` to it, so that it knows which ones should get the lowest ID.
In this case, we're only interrested in 1 student from each class. So I put in `[STU_CLASS_OF]`. But you also only want the TOP one from each. So I order it by `[total] DESC`

If you then wanted e.g. `TOP 3` from each class instead of `TOP 1`, then you simply change the `WHERE RowNumber = 1` to be 3 instead.

If you only want the data for some specific classes and not everyone like I did, then you simply add your previous `WHERE` clause to the final `SELECT` like this:

```
WHERE RowNumber = 1
    AND (12 - ([STU_CLASS_OF] - 2014)) = 9
    AND (12 - ([STU_CLASS_OF] - 2014)) = 10
```

Comment: if I remove one of the order by, then I would get incorrect data

Comment: You need to remove the parentheses as well. Don't try to `UNION` 2 subselects. Do it as I did. Simply have 2 different SELECTs and then write `UNION` between them. No parentheses.

Comment: But that's actually besides the point, really. Because you don't even need the `UNION`. Just alter your `WHERE` clause like @Racil Hilan's updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `UNION` you cannot use `ORDER BY` in the sub-queries. I'm sure there is a better solution, but wrapping your sub-queries in another level will work for you. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 stu_first, stu_last, SUM(kind_hours) AS total 
 FROM student
 INNER JOIN kind ON student.stu_id = kind.stu_id
 WHERE (12-(stu_class_of-2014)) = 9
 GROUP BY stu_first, stu_last
 ORDER BY total DESC)

UNION

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 stu_first, stu_last, SUM(kind_hours) AS total 
 FROM student
 INNER JOIN kind ON student.stu_id = kind.stu_id
 WHERE (12-(stu_class_of-2014)) = 10
 GROUP BY stu_first, stu_last
 ORDER BY total DESC)
```

Comment: i tried this, but i gives me two students from the same grade

Comment: when i put in the grades of 11 and 12

Comment: @user3499265 Yes, I noticed that after I posted it. I've updated my answer, you can try it now.